# PHP Parse HTML img tag src path not working

Tags: php, html, path

i have some code in HTML that gets parsed by PHP, and i want the image tags to be relative, because the code needs to work on multiple servers.

I have `index.php` in the directory as the folder `icons`, and in `icons`, there is an image called `logo.png`. The code is `index.php` is like this:

```
echo '<img src="icons/logo.png">';
```

But does not work. However, if i change it to this kind of path (`http://mydomain...`) it does work.

On one of the servers, both `index.php` and `icons` are in a subdomain directory, and on the other server they are in the root. In both cases the relative path does not work.

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT: In my HTML inspector, i can see that the URL to the image is correctly being parsed.

Comment: this is not an absolute path `http://mydomain..` check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: It's just an example... it actually is: `http://mydomain.com/icons/logo.png`

Comment: still not an absolute path, this is an http address wich is used to redirect user to your public_html folder `/home/username/public_html/` could be an absolute path for example

Comment: O, I'm sorry, then this is the kind of path that does work. Not an absolute path.

Comment: anyway i guess if you use absolute path then it will work

Comment: That's the problem. It needs to work on multiple servers (different domains), so the path has to be relative...

Comment: According to your set up, it should work. You can try to temporarily move logo.png to the same folder as index and setting src=logo.png to check if it works.

Comment: Check my own answer for problem & solution.

Comment: that is not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, i found the problem!
There is no need for complicated solutions, as the problem is this:

```
 icons/
```

When going to `http://mydomain.com/icons`, i find myself in some apache folder containing apache icons.
So i guess it takes me to the very root of the domain, and into some icons folder.

When changing `icons/` to for example `images/`, it works perfectly!

Comment: this is not a solution but rather a hack. Today you dont have images folder in root apache folder therefore you need to rename all your folders/files not to match apache root files/folders. Instead I would read my answer more and maybe read up more on VHosts and htaccess rewrite rules to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in the root directory public_html/ then you dont need to do anything just access it using `/icons/logo.png`. However if you have subdirectory that you want it to be the root directory for itself then do the following:

You need to set up `Virtual Host` for apache if you have access to `httpd-vhosts` and link it to the subdirectory to be the root directory for all files/folder under it.

Then you would just use `"/icons/logo.png"`

If you dont have access to `VHosts` or apache files and you are hosting on shared hosting then you need to read up on **.htaccess** to catch requests and check if img exists in root if not check if it exists in subdirectory.

Another way is to just have a global variable of site URL like:

```
  define('SITE_URL', 'http://mysite.com/');
```

and link to your image like: `<?=SITE_URL?>icons/logo.png`

For each server you would then just modify `SITE_URL`

Comment: Why would i have to do this on a server that is not using a subdomain? Normally i would be able to simple do /icons/logo.png

Comment: because / in front refers to root directory. If you dont use subdirectory you would not need to do anything. You need VHosts or other ways for subdirectories

Comment: Check my own answer for problem & solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to know what is your path in server or in wamp server c:/wamp/www/
so u can put this

```
echo '<'img src="/icons/biglogo.png  >
```

else you need to change your path or put full path

```
echo '<'img src="/mysite/img/icons/biglogo.png" >';
```